# Using #define NDEBUG give me errors in C++

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, ndebug

If I define NDEBUG in the top of my main.cpp I get all this errors:

```
1>  All outputs are up-to-date.
1>libcmt.lib(invarg.obj) : error LNK2005: __initp_misc_invarg already defined in LIBCMTD.lib(invarg.obj)
1>libcmt.lib(invarg.obj) : error LNK2005: __invoke_watson already defined in LIBCMTD.lib(invarg.obj)
1>libcmt.lib(invarg.obj) : error LNK2005: __set_invalid_parameter_handler already defined in LIBCMTD.lib(invarg.obj)
1>libcmt.lib(invarg.obj) : error LNK2005: __get_invalid_parameter_handler already defined in LIBCMTD.lib(invarg.obj)
1>libcmt.lib(invarg.obj) : error LNK2005: "void __cdecl _invoke_watson(unsigned short const *,unsigned short const *,unsigned short const *,unsigned int,unsigned int)" (?_invoke_watson@@YAXPBG00II@Z) already defined in LIBCMTD.lib(invarg.obj)
1>libcmt.lib(invarg.obj) : error LNK2005: __invalid_parameter already defined in LIBCMTD.lib(invarg.obj)
1>libcmt.lib(invarg.obj) : error LNK2005: "void __cdecl _invalid_parameter(unsigned short const *,unsigned short const *,unsigned short const *,unsigned int,unsigned int)" (?_invalid_parameter@@YAXPBG00II@Z) already defined in LIBCMTD.lib(invarg.obj)
1>libcmt.lib(invarg.obj) : error LNK2005: ___pInvalidArgHandler already defined in LIBCMTD.lib(invarg.obj)
1>libcpmtd.lib(xdebug.obj) : warning LNK4098: defaultlib 'libcmt.lib' conflicts with use of other libs; use /NODEFAULTLIB:library
```

I'm using MS Visual Studio 2010, boost and gosu libs.

Comment: Don't do that.  Or use the linker's /NODEFAULTLIB option.  Switching to the Release configuration is the smart way.

Answer (score 1):

This most likely occurs due to a mismatch between included headers (which will be release version if you define `NDEBUG`) and linked libraries, which appear to be debug-versions. Maybe some of the headers rely on auto-linking features, and thus you get different versions of a library linked.

Answer (score 0):

This is because MSVC already defines `NDEBUG` for you in Release build. You shouldn't `#define _DEBUG` or `#define NDEBUG` yourself, use the pre-provided `#define`s.

Comment: No, I was defining NDEBUG in the Debug build.